# Percentage change in K.E for a given change in momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics, momentum

I couldn't get through this 'easy question' that was in my morning exam, it goes

Q. *If linear momentum of body is increased by 50%, then K.E of that body increases by....%*

**My solution **

K.E = $E=\frac{P^2}{2m}$-----(1)

differentiating w.r.t P
$$dE=\frac{2PdP}{2m}$$

divide by E on both sides gives
$$\frac{dE}{E}=\frac{2PdP}{2mE}$$

again put value of E from eqn..(1) simplifies to$$\frac{dE}{E}=\frac{2dP}{P}$$ putting $\frac{dP}{P}$= 0.5, final answer comes 100%

But correct answer is 125%, what is wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation
$$\frac{dE}{E}=\frac{2dP}{P} \tag{1}$$
is only valid for infinitesimal small differentials $dE$ and $dP$.

Thus using differences (instead of differentials) in
$$\frac{\Delta E}{E}\approx \frac{2\Delta P}{P} \tag{2}$$
is only valid if
$\frac{\Delta E}{E}\ll 1$ and $\frac{\Delta P}{P}\ll 1$.

But in your case it is $\frac{\Delta P}{P}=0.5$
which is clearly not $\ll 1$, and therefore (2) is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to calculate the percent change of a function consider that:
$$\text{percent change}={|f(x_f)-f(x_i)|\over f(x_i)}\times 100\%.$$
So, considering that $E(p)=p^2/2m$:
$${{p^2(1+0.5)^2\over 2m}-{p^2\over 2m}\over {p^2\over 2m}}\times 100\%=[(1+0.5)^2-1]\times 100\%=[2.25-1]\times 100\%=125\%.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that 125% is the correct answer:

$E_0$ = m$v_0^2$/2

Assuming constant mass, $v_1 = 1.5 v_0$

$E_1$ = m$v_1^2$/2 = 2.25m$v_0^2$/2

($E_1$ - $E_0$)/$E_0$ = 1.25

Answer (score 1):

Just to follow up on the answer from @Thomas Fritsch that your dE/E = 2dp/p is only valid for infinitesimals, let's integrate.

$\int dE/E$ = 2 $\int dp/p$  where we take as limits E$_1$ to $E_2$ and $p_1$ to $p_2$.

So we have

ln($E_2$) - ln($E_1$) = 2(ln($p_2$) - ln($p_1$))

But $p_2$ = 1.5$p_1$ so using the rule for the logarithm of a product, the right hand side becomes

2(ln(1.5) + ln($p_1$) - ln($p_1$)) = 2ln(1.5)

Similarly, let $E_2$ = x $E_1$ and the left hand side becomes ln(x).

So ln(x) = 2ln(1.5) ---> x = 2.25 and

($E_2$ - $E_1$)/$E_1$ = 1.25